# When I POST to a page, javascript function isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am experiencing a weird issue... when I load the page the first time this works completely:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});    
</script>
```

but if I try POSTing to the same page again, with my "Add" or "Remove" button, the above function doesn't work any longer. In other works, the phone field will be perfect and filtered when the page is first loaded, but when you try and add more club fields, the phone filter no longer works. Why isn't the phone field being masked anymore, am I doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <!-- Basic Page Needs -->

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
        <!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        <!-- css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework.css">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
           $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
        });    
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <!-- header -->
            <div data-role="header" class="page-header">

            </div>
            <!--/header -->

            <form style="" method="POST">
                <fieldset style="text-align: center;">
                    <label for="phone">Cell Phone</label>
                    <input type="tel" id="phone" style="" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['phone'])) echo $_POST['phone'];?>" name="phone" />


                    <br />
                    <?php

                    if(isset($_POST['add']))
                        $_POST['club_num']++;
                    if(isset($_POST['remove']) && $_POST['club_num'] > 1)
                        $_POST['club_num']--;
                    if(!isset($_POST['club_num']))
                        $_POST['club_num'] = 1;

                    ?>

                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['club_num'])) echo $_POST['club_num'];?>" name="club_num" />
                    <h3 style="font-size: 1.5em; margin-top: 40px;">Are you in a Club?</h3>
                    <?php

                    $count = 0;
                    do {
                        $count++;
                        ?>

                        <label for="clubs<?=$count?>"><?=$count?>. Club</label>

                        <input type='text' id="clubs<?=$count?>" name="clubs<?=$count?>" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['clubs'.$count])) echo $_POST['clubs'.$count];?>" />
                        <?php if($count == $_POST['club_num']){ ?>
                            <div style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;" data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                                <input data-theme="e" data-icon="plus" type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
                                <input data-theme="e" data-icon="minus" <?=($_POST['club_num']==1)?'disabled="disabled"':''?> data-iconpos="right" type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove"/>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                    } while ($count < $_POST['club_num']);
                    ?>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <br />

            <!-- footer -->
            <div data-role="footer" class="footer">
                <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /footer -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("#phone")` only deals with the element that has `id='phone'`. If you are adding more fields you should use a different selector.

Comment: @developerwjk I don't think you understand my problem. I only have and need one phone field.... after you POST to the page, it no longer works tho.

Comment: Have you tried using `$( document ).ready(function()`? That might do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this problem, by using **jd182** answer and **jeroen** comment and link here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html

Since it is submitting an ajax form, like jd182 stated, and because it was mobile jquery, all post automatically send as a ajax post.

All I had to do was change

```
<form style="" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form style="" method="POST" data-ajax="false">
```

and it fixed the problem, because it posted regularly!

Thanks jeroen and jd182!

Answer (score 1):

When one of the buttons is pressed the page content is reloaded using AJAX. This means the original element '#phone' (that you bound the mask function to) is replaced.

I can't see where you are doing the AJAX request from, but you need to call `$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");` again once the page has reloaded.

Comment: I don't think I am using ajax... all the code I have is posted to the page.

Comment: The strange thing is that it works perfectly on a mobile device, but not on a desktop browser.

Comment: The OP is using jQuery mobile and that causes the ajax form submission instead of a regular form post: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html

Comment: If I open the console and click one of the buttons it makes an XHR request to reload the page. How do the plus and minus buttons work? Are they something to do with jQuery mobile?

Comment: Ah i see, that explains it. Sorry, i'm not familiar with jQuery mobile so can't really help with that. Maybe someone else knows more about it?

Comment: @jeroen You link helped me solve the problem, adding `data-ajax="false"` to my form fixed it!